# how to refactor javascript code using functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn functional programming using JavaScript form a text book. I have to refactor some code using functional programming and its hard. how do I re-write this code using `map()`, `filter()`, and `reduce()`.

I have to re-write the following code in a more functional way. I have tried but I keep getting empty arrays.

```js
const students = [{
    name: "Anna",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [4.5, 3.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Dennis",
    sex: "m",
    country: "Germany",
    grades: [5, 1.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Martha",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [5, 4, 2.5, 3]
  },
  {
    name: "Brock",
    sex: "m",
    grades: [4, 3, 2]
  }
];

// Compute female student results
const femaleStudentsResults = [];
for (const student of students) {
  if (student.sex === "f") {
    let gradesSum = 0;
    for (const grade of student.grades) {
      gradesSum += grade;
    }
    const averageGrade = gradesSum / student.grades.length;
    femaleStudentsResults.push({
      name: student.name,
      avgGrade: averageGrade
    });
  }
}

console.log(femaleStudentsResults);
```

The results must be identical to this:

`[Object{avgGrade: 4, name: 'Anna'}, Object{avgGrade: 3.625, name: 'Martha'}]`

I started by separating all the female students with

`const females = students.filter(gender => gender.sex === 'f')`

Then, to return the an array of the grades I did

`const grade = females.map(grade => grade.grades);`

But when I try to find an average for the grades using `reduce()`:

```
 const grade = females
   .map(grade => grade.grades)
   .reduce((accum,curr)=>accum + curr)
```

I get the following result `4.5,3.5,45,4,2.5,3`. How can I prevent this and only get the average for each individual students grade average?

Comment: Hey Michaelangelo, I think that part of your problem is that you are mis-understanding what your `map` statement is doing. Your `map` is actually returning only the grades, which is then sent to your reduce function. You aren't performing any operation on the grades either, which based on the previous code, looks like you want to generate an average here and store it in the object.

Comment: yes after reviewing the code i understand, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` (to get female students) followed by `.map` (to transform a student object into an object with the `avgGrade`) instead:

```js
const students = [{
    name: "Anna",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [4.5, 3.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Dennis",
    sex: "m",
    country: "Germany",
    grades: [5, 1.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Martha",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [5, 4, 2.5, 3]
  },
  {
    name: "Brock",
    sex: "m",
    grades: [4, 3, 2]
  }
];

const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
const femaleStudentsResults = students
  .filter(({ sex }) => sex === 'f')
  .map(({ name, grades }) => ({ name, avgGrade: grades.reduce(sum) / grades.length }));
console.log(femaleStudentsResults);
```

Comment: wow i never ever thought of that and i tried for hours which forced me to read a few more books. do you mind telling me which books you used or recommend? thanks in advance

Comment: I've never read any, unfortunately - I learned by experimenting, Googling, watching others' answers here on SO, and chatting on IRC